# Asp.net Full calendar convert time format

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a problem with asp.net full calender. Actually when i am using it my events comes with time "80 min" format.

But i want it in "1:20 min" format

Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish your requirement,use [`TimeSpan.FromMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromminutes.aspx) as shown below :-

```
var result = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(80);
```

`TimeSpan.FromMinutes` will give you an **object** that you can use in different ways as shown below.

```
var hours = (int)result.TotalHours;
var minutes = result.Minutes;

var time = string.Format("{0} : {1}", hours, minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform simple mathemetical calculations like this:

```
//minutes to be converted (70minutes = 1:10 hours)
int totalminutes = 70;
//total hours
int hours = 70 / 60;
//total minutes
int minutes = 70 % 60;
//output is 1:10
var time = string.Format("{0} : {1}", hours, minutes);
```